# How to deal with huge queries to the Facebook Graph?

Tags: facebook, algorithm, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'd like to get every status update for every friend. Given I have say 500 friends, each with 200 statuses, this could be 100,000 statuses. How would you approach this from the query point of view?

What query would you write? Would Facebook allow this much data to come through in a single go? If not is there a best practice paging or offsetting solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would Facebook allow this much data to come through in a single go?

No. Facebook will throw exception of too much data. Also there is automated system in place which will block time-consuming requests as well as it will block your app if it is making too much queries too frequently on a single table - API Throttling Warnings.

> If not is there a best practice paging or offsetting solution?

You can do paging in FQL and when querying connections in graph. It is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

From their policy:

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

It means that 100k is not so big deal. However, it depends. You may have to consider,

- Do you REALLY need every status?
- Can't they be downloaded later?
- Do you need these posts/stories from every friend?

Comment: Thanks - To do it *right* I would, but I need to be realistic.

Comment: Could you define MAU and API  - it wasn't clear from the policy and I'm sure future readers would find it useful.

Comment: @JackKinsella: API you know what it is. MAU = monthly active users, thanks OffBySome